# Broadcast error when using autofeat for automated feature engineering

Tags: data-science, kaggle, feature-engineering

When trying to use autofeat(https://github.com/cod3licious/autofeat) to automatically generate new features, I am receiving the following error:

> operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (963,) (962,)

simple code:

```
model = AutoFeatRegression(n_jobs=-1,verbose=1,max_gb=1)
X_new = model.fit_transform(X,y)
```

where X and y are both pandas data frame.

Comment: What kind of dataset do you have?